# Initialize class static map with 60K+ entries

Tags: c++, c++11, static

I have a class like this:

```
class AntennaController
{
    public:
        static map<uint16_t, uint64_t> channel_to_freq;
        static map<uint64_t, uint16_t> freq_to_channel;
};
```

These two maps convert transmit frequencies to channels, and vice versa (i.e. `140000000 -> 4`, `4 -> 140000000`). There are 65536 different channels.

So my question is: is there a way to initialize these static members without manually listing out all 65536 key-value pairs for each map (i.e. with a for loop)?

And if I don't use a static map so that I can initialize it in the constructor, won't every single instance have its own copy?

Comment: Write a function that uses a loop to populate a map and then return that map from the function.  Then you can call that function in the initializer of the map

Comment: @NathanOliver I agree, but wouldn't it make sense to make that function `constexpr` so it can potentially be evaluated at compile time? Or pre-generate the data and just stick the whole bunch of data in an initializer for the map inside the function so it doesn't have to be generated every time?  At least, that's what *I*'d do..

Comment: @JesperJuhl `std::map` is not `constexpr` (it can't because it is a dynmaic data structure).  Since the maps are static the loop will only be called once.  You could prebuild the initializer list and then just include that but it will make the code base larger and possibly add to the compilation time.  That said I would probably prebuild the list and import it as long as it is not an issue.

Comment: @NathanOliver Ah... I didn't think of that. I was entertaining the idea of writing a python script to generate the C++ initialization list. If you post that as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: This particular case may have been an XY problem though. There is actually a mathematical formula that you can use to calculate the channel from frequency and vice versa, and after some bench marking it seems calling a function with the math formula is even faster than a map lookup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple options.  You could write a static function for the class the builds a map using a for loop and returns the map.  You can then initialize the class member with that function like

```
// header file
class AntennaController
{
    public:
        static map<uint16_t, uint64_t> channel_to_freq;
        static map<uint64_t, uint16_t> freq_to_channel;
        map<uint64_t, uint16_t> build_channel_to_freq { /* code here */ }
        map<uint64_t, uint16_t> build_freq_to_channel { /* code here */ }
};

//cpp file
AntennaController::map<uint16_t, uint64_t> channel_to_freq = build_channel_to_freq();
AntennaController::map<uint64_t, uint16_t> freq_to_channel = build_freq_to_channel();
```

You could also write a script/program that builds an initlaizer list for you, and then you can include that file into your code base.  You could just generate the list and then do something like

```
AntennaController::map<uint16_t, uint64_t> channel_to_freq { #include "channel_to_freq_list.h" }
AntennaController::map<uint16_t, uint64_t> freq_to_channel { #include "freq_to_channel_list.h" }
```

Or you could just have it build the entire thing and have it output a cpp file that you can add to the project.